# Rental Car tolls and administrative fees

Tags: car-rentals, fees-and-charges

It seems car rental companies assess [an administrative fee](http://rentalcarticket.com), in may case with Fox Rent A Car [in SoCal on the 73](http://thetollroads.com/tolls/map-rates) over twice the cost of the tolls, simply for telling renters a few details, again in my case an insufficient amount of details to easily pay the ticket, about tolls assessed to rented vehicles.

Nevertheless, if I had paid the toll within 5 days, would I still be assessed an administrative fee?

Comment: Which rental car company and which toll? The situation varies a lot depending on whether you got a ticket for non-payment, it's a "pay within 24-48 hours" type of toll arrangement, or the rental car company paid the toll on your behalf using a transponder in the rental car.